# SQL query does not return expected result

Tags: sql, select

I am running the examples to be found here: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

I am given a table named world:

[image]

[image]

I would expect this:

[image]

Why do I get this result, and how can I correct my SQL query?

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: Please look at my updated post

Comment: Add code as text not as image

Comment: I believe this is what you need; select continent, [name] from [world] order by continent asc, [name] asc

Comment: @sam that would cleary not return just one country per continent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query returns exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220593/sql-query-returns-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
SELECT distinct continent, 
    ( SELECT name
      FROM world b 
      WHERE a.continent = b.continent 
      ORDER BY name 
      LIMIT 1) 
FROM world a
```

or

```
SELECT  continent, 
 ( SELECT name 
   FROM world b 
   WHERE a.continent = b.continent 
   ORDER BY name 
   LIMIT 1) 
FROM world a
GROUP BY continent
```

You are getting a row for every country in the world and there are many per continent - -you need to limit to just one continent returned in the result set.

> This technique is called a correlated sub-query, if you were wondering.