# SQL query returns exception

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am running the examples to be found here: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

I am given a table named world:

[image]

In this exercise I am getting an exception:

[image]

```
SELECT name, continent, population
FROM world 
WHERE continent IN (
    SELECT continent FROM world x
    WHERE ALL(
        SELECT population FROM world y
        WHERE x.continent = y.continent
    ) <= 25000000
)
```

What is the reason for the exception, and how can I correct my code?

Comment: The exception is the Error message presented in the image in my post.  Please visit the webpage https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial where you will find the exercise

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the value which should `ALL ..` compared to must be in front of `ALL`

```
SELECT name, continent, population
FROM world 
WHERE continent IN (SELECT continent FROM world x WHERE 25000000> ALL(SELECT population FROM world y WHERE x.continent = y.continent) )
```